# ASP.NET MVC Apply different DisplayFormat's for Edit and Display modes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, date

## The Problem

I'm running through the [tutorials for ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) (but I think this would also apply to MVC 5), in which you create a website for a movie store.

The movie model has a ReleaseDate property of type DateTime.
Generally this date is going to be viewed more than it is edited, so I applied the following attributes to render it nicely.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

When a view that **displays** this date renders it using:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```

it's displayed nicely formatted, as you'd expect:

[image: Nicely formatted dates]

But, when a view that **edits** this date renders it using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```

it displays a lovely HTML5 date picker, but doesn't fill in the value because the date's in the wrong format (error message is `The specified value '11/01/1989 00:00:00' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.`
This is a problem, because if a user wants to edit an entry, the date from the control never gets set, so the user won't know what the previous/current value is.

[image]

## A Half-way Solution

A solution I've found from reading other similar questions is to set the DisplayFormat in the model to yyyy-MM-dd and make is applicable for edit controls:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

This works, in that it auto populates the value for the HTML5 date picker during editing (using `@Html.EditorFor())`:

[image]

But I'm stuck with ugly ISO format dates for when I'm displaying (using `@Html.DisplayFor()):

[image]

## The Real Question

My real question is: **can I have different display formats for normal display and editing mode, set in the model?**

- I don't want to use a textbox for editing the date - I want to use the HTML5 date picker; it's much nicer than using a textbox.
- I also don't really want to change all the views that display the date to directly get the property from the model and format it with custom formatting, that kinda negates the point of the DisplayFormat attribute. (I want to use `@Html.DisplayFor` for displaying and `@Html.EditorFor` for editing)

## Edit

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] // use this format for edit controls
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)] // use this format for display controls
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

but you can't have two display format attributes for one property.

Comment: Do you *have* to use DisplayFor? You can also use @Model.ReleaseDate.ToString() with a  format string matching the output you want.

Comment: @TiesonT. I don't have to... it's just so nice and neat. My main issue is that by using @model.ReleaseDate.ToString() with a format string is that that format string has to be replicated everywhere that the release date is displayed, which is going to be many more places than it is edited. I've just seen your comment in Backs answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use format parameter for method TextBoxFor and override the type attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReleaseDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", htmlAttributes: new { @type="date" })
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question; I don't want to use a text box for the date. If you use a textbox you don't get the HTML5 date picker.

Comment: @JamesCrawshaw you can override the type attribute in the htmlAttribute parameter.

Comment: @TiesonT. @Backs It works! Thanks a lot!. The code I ended up using was: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReleaseDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", htmlAttributes: new {type="date"})`. @Backs - if you edit your answer, or @TiesonT. - if you post an answer with this code I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: If you would be using this quite a bit, it may also make sense to wrap it into an extension. Then you wouldn't have to repeat the same override everywhere.

Comment: Not a bad idea, that. Thanks!