# MVC project: Convert user input date mmddyyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a textbox in a MVC project that prompts a user to enter a date as mmddyyyy. I have the code set up so that the user can only input numbers (ie, no "/"s or "-"s). I need to then convert this data to yyyy-mm-dd to ensure that correct data is being added to the database once the form is submitted.

I realize I will probably need to use DateTime.Parse to do this, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add it to the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Buy2IDExpireDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Buy2IDExpireDate, new { id = "coBuyerIDExpireDate", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Buy2IDExpireDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it look something like this?

```
string str = Date.Parse(Buy2IDExpireDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If so where do I put it in the above code, and do I need to write extra code to ensure that the newly formatted date is stored by the database?

Comment: "I need to then convert this data to yyyy-mm-dd to ensure that correct data is being added to the database once the form is submitted." Is your database field a string then? I'd strongly recommend you to use a date field instead, and then you don't need to worry about the format.

Comment: Hi Jon, yes it is a Date field.

Comment: Right, so don't convert it back to a string at all. You should take care about how you parse it from a string *to* a `DateTime`, but then you should pass that `DateTime` value to the database as a parameter.

Comment: please check this link useful about datetime format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993584/asp-net-mvc-apply-different-displayformats-for-edit-and-display-modes

Answer (score 0):

You can add `value` attribute like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Buy2IDExpireDate,
           new { @Value = Model.Buy2IDExpireDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

Comment: @cryan Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question! (not to mention which is terrible practice to set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method)